# Calculation based on 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to add a field in a form, where a user can use timePicker to select a start_time and an end_time for a shift, and this will then populate a field named total_hours with the difference between the 2 other input fields.

```
function findTotalHours(){

var start_time = parseInt(document.getElementById("start_time").value);
var end_time = parseInt(document.getElementById("end_time").value);
var sub_start = start_time.substr(0,1);
var sub_end = end_time.substr(0,1);
var result = sub_end - sub_start;
document.getElementById('total_hours').value = result; 
}
```

I'm getting console errors of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'substr'
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object 9 has no method 'substr' (var sub_start =
>   start_time.substr(0,1);)

timePicker stores the time as `hh:mm` format, so I'm trying to remove the minutes and the colon for now, to try to get total_hours displaying, before I think about how to handle the minutes.

Any advice on how to fix this code, and possibly how to handle the minutes, in that format will be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bpw6Y/

Comment: Could you provide complete JSFiddle example ?

Comment: start_time and end_time inputs contain incorrect number

Comment: Look below for answer dude

Comment: Hi @danielsmile, I gave you a solution below, but I would also like to point out that by using parseInt(), you are setting start_time and end_time to be Integers. Integer data types do not have a substring function, which would be why you are getting those errors.

Comment: Check my answer for minutes solution - I think I have the solution to your errors too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you first read in the values from your two inputs, then parse them as Date objects, and then perform the subtraction (I include the absolute function to compensate for switched values). Here is a possible solution:

```
var date_1 = document.getElementById("date_1").value;
var date_2 = document.getElementById("date_2").value;

var d_1 = Date.parse(date_1);
var d_2 = Date.parse(date_2);
var diff_milliseconds = Math.abs(d_2 - d_1);
var diff_hours = diff_milliseconds / 1000 / 60 / 60;

alert(diff_hours + " hours difference");
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Ralfe

Comment: Gives alert NaN hours difference

Comment: Did you remember to change the "date_1" and "date_2" to whatever the ID's of your inputs are?

Comment: Ok, but in JSFiddle, you still need to create the two input fields, otherwise there is no input data to work with, which would cause the errors. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/TGXg9/1/

Comment: My apologies ralfe, i used jsfiddle just to show you the JS code, I tested the code in my actual code.

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided in my last comment? Click on the button and see the answer in a javascript popup. http://jsfiddle.net/TGXg9/1/

Comment: Yes I have checked it out, the error occurs when the values being entered are changed. I've updated your fiddle to show this http://jsfiddle.net/92sG5/. Your solution is ideal, if it can work with this type of value.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is with the format; it cannot be parsed by Javascript. If the times will always be within the same day, then the solution is very simple. Take a look at the updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/92sG5/

Comment: Yes, the times will always be within the same day, I take the date in a seperate input field as I use this for other things. The fiddle you pasted seems to be the old one, not an updated version. You will need to fork it and send the updated link.

Answer (score 0):

By using `parseInt` you are converting the values from the two input tags to numbers.

You are getting the

`Uncaught TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'substr'`

error because the value returned after `parseInt` is NaN(Not a Number) which means the value from the `#start_time` input is not valid.

You are getting the

`Uncaught TypeError: Object 9 has no method 'substr' (var sub_start = start_time.substr(0,1);)`

error because `substr` is a String prototype method and `start_time` and `end_time` are Numbers. You might want to use

`var sub_start = (start_time+'').substr(0,1);`
instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findTotalHours() {

        var start_time = document.getElementById("start_time").value;
        var end_time = document.getElementById("end_time").value;

        var sub_start = start_time.substr(0, 2);    //Make sure date formate will be HH like 03,09 not 3,9
        var sub_end = end_time.substr(0, 2);
        var result = parseInt(sub_end) - parseInt(sub_start);     

        document.getElementById('total_hours').value = result;
    }


  </script>
```

Comment: Updated please check now

Comment: Works now, thanks! If you know how this can be adapted to also include the minutes, please let me know

Comment: This link might help out http://jsfiddle.net/BSeN6/2/. Please accept as answer above things works fine.